# passing an ofstream object to a thread function via pthread_create

Tags: pthreads, pass-by-reference

I want to pass an ofstream object to a thread using pthread_create function. 
Let's say I create an object like this in my main(int argc, char *argv[]) function.

```
ofstream file1(argv[1], fstream::out|fstream::app);
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, (void *)args);
```

And the function1 is defined as.

```
void function1(void *input)
{
      ofstream file;
      file = ??
      file << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

How can I access "file1.txt" created in the main function via the file object?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to pass the object.  One would be to make it global, then then it's very straightforward for `function1()` to access it.  Or you can pass a pointer to it as the thread's argument.  Cast it to `void*` in the `pthread_create()` call and cast it back in the thread function.

```
void* function1(void *input) {
      ofstream* file = static_cast<ofstream*>(input);
      *file << "Hello" << endl;
      return NULL;
}
ofstream file1("./file1.txt", fstream::out|fstream::app);
pthread_t tid;
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, static_cast<void*>(&file1));
```

Be warned, there is a common bug that this pattern often leads to!  The ofstream will be destructed when the scope it was created in ends, which is in the thread that called `pthread_create()`.  If the thread running `function1()` is still running, it could use the pointer to the now destructed ofstream.

You need to insure that the ofstream remains alive until the other thread is done with it.  One way would be to give it static storage duration, either as a static local variable or as a global variable.  Another would to allocate it with `new` and then `delete` it in the thread that is using it.  Or you could insure that the created thread is joined before the ifstream leaves scope.

Using `new` and `delete`:

```
void start(void) {
    ofstream* file1 = new ofstream("file1.txt", fstream::app);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, static_cast<void*>(file1));
    file1 = NULL;  // function1 owns this now, shouldn't be used here anymore
}
void* function1(void* arg) {
    ofstream* file1 = static_cast<ofstream*>(arg);
    delete file1;
}
```

Joining before the ofstream leaves scope:

```
void start(void) {
    {
        ofstream file1("file1.txt", fstream::app);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, function1, static_cast<void*>(file1));
        // stuff
        pthread_join(tid);
        // now it's safe for file1 to be destructed.
    }
}
```

Also note that the thread function should return `void*`, not `void`.  Also it should be declared as `extern "C"` so that it will have the correct ABI when the C pthreads library calls it.  Notice how in the new/delete example, I set the pointer to `NULL` after starting the thread.  This is because you can not assume it is safe to access the `ofstream` from more than one thread at a time.  By setting it to `NULL`, only the `function1` thread will be able to access it.

Consider also, maybe it makes more sense to pass the name to the thread and have it open the file?  This solves the issues around the lifetime of the object vs the lifetime of the thread using it.

Comment: Actually I wanted to determine the filename using command line arguments. When the ofstream object is declared globally, is it still possible?

Comment: Yes, just use the default constructor of `ofstream` and then call the `open()` method later when the filename is available.